# How I can open pdf file I made

Tags: android

```
    private static final int WRITE_REQUEST_CODE = 101;
        private void createFile() {
    
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
    
            intent.setType("application/pdf");
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
         intent.setType("*/*");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, title);
    
        startActivityForResult(intent, WRITE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
    
     @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    creat_pdf_income(data.getData());
    }
    
      public void creat_pdf_income(final Uri uri) {
     PdfDocument myPdfDocument = new PdfDocument();
    .
    .
         myPdfDocument.finishPage(myPage[i]);
    .
    .
          OutputStream outputStream;
            try {
                outputStream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
                myPdfDocument.writeTo(outputStream);
    
             
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    
            myPdfDocument.close();
// this for open it
     Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }
```

I managed to make pdf file .  But how  can I open it after create it .
some time it open automatcly . and some time i get error . I dont know what I did wrong
[this the message I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8h1O9.png)

Comment: If you wanna let it open by other apps then use ACTION_VIEW.

Comment: when I do that it show empty file , or error ,maybe the Url file not exist after I mypdfdocument.close()

Comment: If you do it without code...

Comment: Add a mime type. And show what you use for uri. Put complete code in your post. Not in a comment.

Comment: I tried this (opened in some devices but I got error in some)
 Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                        startActivity(browserIntent);

Comment: Thinks for helping me , I add the code

Comment: Any reason why you did not add a mime type? And which app is displaying that error? And add a flag for grand read uri permission.

Comment: It not working , I tried with mime type .

Comment: Please show full code. Edit your post to do so.And why didnt you try with that flag?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view PDF files within your own app, you can try this library:
https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

First you have to include it in your gradle:

```
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
```

Then, you add the PDFView in the XML of your Activity or Fragment:

```
<com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
    android:id="@+id/pdfView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Finally, load the PDF file into the PDFView with either a URI or File object:

```
PDFView pdfView = findViewById(R.id.pdfView);

pdfView.fromUri(Uri);
//OR
pdfView.fromFile(File);
```

Comment: I want to open it with any other pdf viewer. Just after wine it made. Automatically.